# Counting posts in custom post type by author

Tags: count

I have googled this a few different ways, but cannot find the answer I'm looking for. I want to be able to count the number of posts each author has within a custom post type. Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this code wordpress.org . This code would work in author template.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>
<h2>Post Count: <?php echo $post_count; ?></h2>
```

But if you wish to use it somewhere else then replace `$curauth->ID` with author id and `post` with the post type you want

it should work .
All the best

Comment: I will give this a try. I have seen the $curauth variable used before, but not with the query. Surprised I didn't find this if it was on Wordpress. Thanks!

Comment: :) glad was able to help you

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
// get author ID
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ); 

// echo count for post type (post and book)
echo  count_user_posts( $author_id , ['post','book']  ); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
    if you're on a page, it will return the page object
    if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
    if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
    if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object
etc.
```

Use [query-object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) as suggested by @terminator

In place of using sql query use [count_user_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/)

```
  $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    count_user_posts($queried_object->ID, 'custom_post_type_here');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in `functions.php`

```
 function count_posts_by_author($post_type){
   global $wp_query;
   $curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => $post_type,
     'author'        =>  $curauth->ID,
     'posts_per_page' => -1 // no limit
   );
   echo count(get_posts($args));
 }
```

and just call the function in your template file

```
<?php count_posts_by_author('Your post type or custom post type');?>
```